# Update Div Hidden Field on jQuery Sortable Drag and Drop Update

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I am using an HTML5 jQuery Sortable library.  Not jQuery UI Sortable but this one here http://farhadi.ir/projects/html5sortable/

I have used it on many projects in the past and generally I use AJAX to save the sort order as a string of ID's into a database field.

On my current project, I need to do things completely different though.  I am not using AJAX to save the order this time.

Basically I have the Sortable library running on a Form edit screen which will have a list of DIV's, inside these div's will be form fields.  At the bottom of the page is a save button that submits the form to save all the data on the page.  So I would like to instead store the sort order of each DIV into a hidden form field for each item.

I have set up a demo to work with on CodePen.io here http://codepen.io/jasondavis/pen/ztirw?editors=101

I could use some help to update a Form filed under each Div to update the fields with the Sort order each time a Drop occurs.   So instead of saving a string of ID's in the correct sorted order, I would instead like to update every record on a Drop event into a Form filed with the current sort position.

Any help please?

The demo HTML structure looks like this...

```
<div id="project_tasks" class="tasks_block sortable">

    <div id="task_13" class="task_row">
        <span class="handle"></span>
        <input name="taskid_13" id="taskid_13" size="15" type="text" value="taskID 1">
        <input name="projectid_13" id="projectid_13" size="15" type="text" value="917fdb60-96d7-346f-10b3-54175c9a2f34">
        Sort Order: <input name="sort_order_19" id="sort_order_19" size="15" type="text" value="1">
        <br style="clear:both;">

    </div>

    <div id="task_14" class="task_row">
        <span class="handle"></span>
        <input name="taskid_14" id="taskid_14" size="15" type="text" value="taskID 2">
        <input name="projectid_14" id="projectid_14" size="15" type="text" value="917fdb60-96d7-346f-10b3-54175c9a2f34">
        Sort Order: <input name="sort_order_19" id="sort_order_19" size="15" type="text" value="2">
        <br style="clear:both;">
    </div>

    <div id="task_15" class="task_row">
        <span class="handle"></span>
        <input name="taskid_15" id="taskid_15" size="15" type="text" value="taskID 3">
        <input name="projectid_15" id="projectid_15" size="15" type="text" value="917fdb60-96d7-346f-10b3-54175c9a2f34">
        Sort Order: <input name="sort_order_19" id="sort_order_19" size="15" type="text" value="3">
        <br style="clear:both;">
    </div>


    <div id="task_15" class="task_row taskheading">
        <span class="handle"></span>
        <h2>List Heading 1</h2>
        Sort Order: <input name="sort_order_19" id="sort_order_19" size="15" type="text" value="4">
        <br style="clear:both;">
    </div>  



    <div id="task_16" class="task_row">
        <span class="handle"></span>
        <input name="taskid_16" id="taskid_16" size="15" type="text" value="taskID 4">
        <input name="projectid_16" id="projectid_16" size="15" type="text" value="917fdb60-96d7-346f-10b3-54175c9a2f34">
        Sort Order: <input name="sort_order_19" id="sort_order_19" size="15" type="text" value="5">
        <br style="clear:both;">
    </div>

</div>
```

A little JavaScript to start things off...

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    $('#project_tasks').sortable({
        handle: '.handle',
        onStartDrag: function() {},
        onEndDrag: function() {},
        onChangeOrder: function() {}
    }).bind('sortupdate', function() {


        $('.sortable div').each(function() {

            // Update a HIDDEN Field under each DIV with the current sort order
            // So when my Form is submitted/saved, it can save the sort order for
            // each record into the database.

        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok - here you go:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IEKvA

```
 $('.sortable div').each(function(idx) {

          var inputField = $(this).find("[id^='sort_order']");
          $(inputField).val(idx);

  });
```

The idea is to everytime and item is dropped you run thru your divs, find all the input fields that start with the id sort_order and set the index accordingly.

Comment: Great, I had just came up with a solution like this...

        `var listElements = $('.sortable div');`
        `for(var i = 0; i < listElements.length; i++){`
        `$(listElements[i]).children('.sortorder').attr({`value: i+1});`
        `}` 
    `});`
`});`  But I like your solution even better, thanks!